# Lot of sleeping queries running on mysql process

Tags: linux, mysql, centos7

We have 150 databases running on the server and sometimes it is causing "too many connections" issue and also there are lot of sleeping queries running on the MySQL process. The sleeping queries time is over 200. Please find the server my.cnf configuration below. I have increased the max_connections 500 to 750 but the connections sometimes increasing over 750. is it safe to increase max_connections to 1000 or any additional configuration need in the my.cnf? Can you please any one help me, if anything missing on the configurations.

```
[mysqld]
performance-schema=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
symbolic-links=0

log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
query_cache_type=1

slow_query_log=1
slow_query_log_file="/var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log"
max_connections = 750
default-storage-engine=MyISAM
innodb_file_per_table=1
max_allowed_packet=268435456
open_files_limit=43000
bind-address=0.0.0.0
innodb_buffer_pool_size= 6G
wait_timeout = 300
key_buffer_size = 2G
read_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 512M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 2M
sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
query_cache_limit = 536870912
query_cache_size = 268435456
```

Threads Running On Mysql

```
mysql> show status like "%Threads%";
+------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name          | Value |
+------------------------+-------+
| Delayed_insert_threads | 0     |
| Slow_launch_threads    | 0     |
| Threads_cached         | 12    |
| Threads_connected      | 659   |
| Threads_created        | 38451 |
| Threads_running        | 1     |
+------------------------+-------+
```

htop results:

```
1  [|      1.3%]   11 [       0.0%]   21 [       0.0%]   31 [       0.0%]
2  [||     3.2%]   12 [||||  29.5%]   22 [       0.0%]   32 [       0.0%]
3  [       0.0%]   13 [       0.0%]   23 [|      0.6%]   33 [       0.0%]
4  [|||   21.3%]   14 [||||  26.1%]   24 [||     2.6%]   34 [       0.0%]
5  [|      0.6%]   15 [|      0.6%]   25 [||     1.9%]   35 [       0.0%]
6  [||||  26.3%]   16 [||     3.2%]   26 [||     1.3%]   36 [       0.0%]
7  [||     1.9%]   17 [||     4.5%]   27 [       0.0%]   37 [       0.0%]
8  [||     3.8%]   18 [||     5.8%]   28 [       0.0%]   38 [       0.0%]
9  [|      0.6%]   19 [       0.0%]   29 [       0.0%]   39 [       0.0%]
10 [||     4.5%]   20 [||     5.1%]   30 [       0.0%]   40 [       0.0%]
Mem[|||||||||||||||||||17.7G/62.7G]   Tasks: 132, 473 thr; 3 running
Swp[|                  89.0M/7.81G]   Load average: 1.03 0.97 0.90 
                                        Uptime: 22 days, 16:31:03 

 PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command
14706 mysql      20   0 29.3G 13.7G 10816 S 12.2 21.9 37h23:37 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

Database Connection Script (PHP):

```
<?php
class setting{  
    private $conn;
    private $dbs;   
    function __construct($cid){
        $client=$this->getclientbyid($cid);     
        $db=new db_bridge($client['website']);
        if(!$db->exist()){
            echo($client['website']." not exist in our DB");
            die;    
        }
        else{
            $db->setid();   
            $this->setdb($db->get());
        }   
   }
   function __destruct(){
    $this->dbs=null;
   }
   function setdb($db){
    $this->conn=$db;
    self::connect();    
   }
   function connect(){
        try{
        $this->dbs=new PDO("mysql:host=".$this->conn['host'].";dbname=".$this->conn['db'], $this->conn['duser'],$pass);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "Unable to connect Database";
        }        
    }
    protected function query($query,$both=false){
        $result=$this->dbs->prepare($query);
        $result->execute();
        if(!$both){
            $rs=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }
        else{
            $rs=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
        }
        return $rs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Could you post the code that 'connects' to your MySQL database, sends request, closes the activity ?

Comment: @WilsonHauck, RAM size : 64BG and CPU cores : 40. I have added the htop results on the questions above, there is mysql process is top on the results.

Comment: There is no code to close the connection - so they are just left sleeping.  In the following URL see Example #3 and adjust appropriately.  Or post the complete template you used for the connection development and further on we should find the 'close' attempt for you to follow.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: RedHat suggests swap size of RAM * .2 - unless server is allowed to hibernate, then set swap size of RAM * 1.2.

Comment: @WilsonHauck, connection was set to null on the destruct function

Comment: Please post to pastebin.com 10 seconds of General Log so we can see a request or two to verify MySQL has the Quit posted for the PID when done.  Thanks

Comment: To be more like Example #3 from the php.net url above, consider adding to your function __destruct() code a line for $result=null;  - to be the equivalent of their $sth = null; and keep us posted on sleeping count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of increasing `max_connections`, it would be better to

- Have clients close connections when finished with them.
- If using "connection pooling", don't set its number too high.
- Fewer client connections allowed (eg, max children in Apache or other web server)
- Decrease `wait_timeout` (so that the Sleeping connections will be automatically disconnected sooner)

The number of sleeping connections does not necessarily reflect anything critically wrong.  The number of concurrently running threads (`SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Threads_running'`) is more important.  It should be no more than a few dozen.  (The "1" you showed would be the `SHOW` command itself; nothing else was "running".)

`max_connections` of a few hundered is high enough for *most* systems.  Please provide the info requested by Wilson; this may give further insight into what the real issues are.

Other issues...

`query_cache_size = 268435456` is too high.  The Query cache does not scale well; limit it to 50M.

In order to get much out of the slowlog, set `long_query_time = 1`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i have added my database connection code and other info on the question above.